# Dynamically deciding what object to interact with by string contents

Tags: c#, console-application

I am working on a console application in C# .Net 6.0 that uses WMPLib that I am trying to turn into a form of MUD game.

I am struggling to allow the player to control what it can attack and 'validate' it is an actual object with a matching correct name.

I have two relevant custom class objects

`Monster tytbric = new();`

`Player player = new();`

Followed by a method that interprets a string

`globals.Command = Console.ReadLine();`

```
public int ReadCommand(string comm)
        {
            if (comm.StartsWith("go"))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if (comm.StartsWith("talk"))
            {
                return 2;
            }
            if (comm.StartsWith("attack"))
                return 3;
            }
        }
```

I then define what is being attacked by taking the second half of globals.Command

(The expected contents of the string would be in the format of  "attack nameofmonster")

```
if (command.ReadCommand(globals.Command) == 3) //attack command 
   {
       string attackingwhat = globals.Command.Split(' ')[1];
       if (attackingwhat == tytbric.name)
       {
           if (player.zoneNum == tytbric.zoneNum && player.coordinate == tytbric.coordinate)
           {
               if (tytbric.Dead == 0)
               {
                   globals.ReturnedCombatStats = statcombatcalcs.MeleeToMeleeCalc(player.maxhp, player.CurrHP, player.strength, player.dexterity, player.level, tytbric.maxhp,
                       tytbric.CurrHP, tytbric.strength, tytbric.dexterity, tytbric.level, tytbric.DisplayName);
                   //player.CurrHP = globals.ReturnedCombatStats[0];
                   tytbric.Dead = globals.ReturnedCombatStats[3];
                   player.Dead = globals.ReturnedCombatStats[4];
                   player.strength += 0.1;
               }
           }
        }
}
```

Although this works with the correct casing, I wanted it to look for an object instance that was named the same as the string value rather than specifying it or by using the property tytbric.Name ? Is that possible or should I implement this / look at this  a different way? I'm quite new to development and this is just a hobby for now.

In the end I hope to have lots of objects with the type of Monster - so allowing a form of string search or similar feels important.

[EDIT] I should add that I have a unique property of `monsterid`

E.g. If(attackingwhat == ObjectOfType(Monster).Property(Name)) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want the answer you are asking for. It's very bad practice to start looking for in-code objects by name (though you can do this with reflection)

In your case, I'd suggest making a `static List<Monster> monsters = new();` somewhere high level, then `.Add` and `.Remove` when monsters spawn/die. Add a `string name` field to the Monsters class, and find the monster by iterating though the list.

It's probably a bit advanced, but you can do this with Linq:

```
monsters.where(x => x.name == userString).FirstOrDefault()
```

You can then attack this object or anything else the object exposes.

Edit: couple of other notes:

Look up enums, they are far better than returning/checking for hard coded `int`s

Also look up the switch statement and patterns that can give.

You may also be interested in `string.split`, as you can split your string into an array of strings (in your case by the space character) to get command/target information seperately.

Happy coding!

Comment: Why a `List<Monster>` instead of a `Dictionary<string, Monster>`? The latter will also usually have faster lookup

Comment: It absolutely would, but realistically you probably won't have sufficient monsters for the performance difference to be relevant (if less than about 2000 to fight in any instance), and I wasn't sure if `name` was unique, or a monster 'type' like goblin or orc.

Comment: The List could also be useful as it stores monsters in the order they are added by default, whereas Dictionaries don't store their contents in any such order.

Comment: Considering you are performing a linear search in combination with string comparison the amount of `Monster` objects where the performance of a dictionary becomes faster may be a lot smaller than you think. String comparisons are quite slow (compared to integer comparisons) so performing one on potentially every single object in a list can quickly become a bottlenek

Comment: To clarify - name, at this moment in time is not unique, however the intention was to allow the zonenum / coordinate values values to make it unique / verify the result but I can see now that ambiguity is causing me problems. I do have a unique number assigner method for monsters in the form of int monsterid. I will edit my post to add this in, as it seems the logical way to search for something from @AndrewWynn suggestion would simply be an int.

I need to refine my code at the same time

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on Enums, will look into how that might benefit my code without adding undue complexity. I will attempt to implement a list to allow me to work with my objects as you've suggested, I will then mark this as the answer. Thanks @UnholySheep for your input too.

Comment: Just to come back and say I implemented a list, and used your implementation of iterating through the list, it's given me the ability to find objects and much more. Looks like it will be very powerful for me, I had only just gotten my head around serialization/deserialization.

Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, hope it goes well for you!